# Pre-calculated JOIN queries as map in ignite

Tags: ignite

I am new to ignite and POCing currently. 
I have a question regarding ways to store/load data in map. It's bit tricky and strange requirement. 
Example:

> I have Employee, Department, Project [Tables in database] + [Entity classes in application]. 
>   But I don't want to store each of these in a separate map in memory but rather I want to store pre-calculated join results in a designated map.

Dynamic Query : select employeeId,employeeName,departmentName,projectName,projectStart,projectEnd from Employee,Department,Project where $JOIN

I know at least before hand that, what would be key fields and what would be value fields. From above example, I can denote my "Map" as shown below,

Key : Set (employeeId,departmentId)
Value : List (employeeName,value),(departmentName,value),(projectName,value),(projectStart,value),(projectEnd,value)

So you can see with every pair of (employeeId,departmentId) I would be having multiple values associates with it. But dilemma is I don't have domain model/entity pojos before hand. Such dynamic views/maps can be added flexibly so that we don't have to go and change domain/entity model every time. **We don't want to do joins/calculations every time for thousands of such client request on every call.**

Is it possible to fire such join queries using MapLoader or by any other means?
I can think of Map with (Key=Set, Value = List)as data structure to store final results.Any other better alternative?

Could there be any performance issues while retrieving values from such map based on keys?
Any memory optimizations I should take care of?

Thanks,
Dharam

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to use SQL queries. It's fine to use Ignite as a simple caching mechanism for DB query results. Each time a query is executed, save the result in IgniteCache and then use this cached result is the same query is requested. You can also use expirations [1] and/or evictions [2] to make sure that you don't have too much data in the cache and don't run out of memory.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/evictions

Comment: But that's what I want to avoid [Each time DB query]. On startup itself, I want to cache all JOINed resultset into memory as I am sure that it's going to be required. But I don't have POJO/domain model, then how I should store them in cache?

If I say Employee or Department, they denote domain/entity model classes. But I don't want to have predefined POJO to store it into cache. I should be able to add dynamic query each resulting into separate map in distributed cache. That's a reason, I mentioned,
Key = Set<Tuple>
Value = List<Tuple>

Comment: I don't want to store database tables in cache and then apply predicate/query to calculate join. Rather I only want to have precalculated JOINed results.

- User1 may say, given A,B I need A1,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5 [Separate Map with Key(A,B) Values(A1,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5)]
- User2 may say, given A,C I need A1,C1,C5 [Separate Map with Key(A,C) Values (A1,C1,C5)]

Comment: Ignite stores the data in binary format, which support dynamic schema changes. If you don't have any classes, you can use builder to create objects: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#modifying-binary-objects-using-binaryobjectbuilder